# Need a field / flag / status number for mutliple use?

Tags: database, database-design

I want to create a field in my database which will be easy to query.

I think if I give a bit of background this will make more sense. My table has listings shown on my website. I run a program which looks at the listings a decides whether to hide them from being shown on the site. I also hide listings manually for various reasons.

I want to store these reasons in a field, so more than one reason could be made for hiding.

So I need some form of logic to determine which reasons have been used.

Can anyone offer me any guidance on what will be future-proof aka new reasons and what will be quick and easy to query upon ?

Comment: What kind of reasons? If it's a small amount of fixed reasons you can use a bit field. If it's != 0 there's at least one reason and you could check for specific reason(s) with a simple bitwise AND. This only works if the reasons are few, fixed and without parameters.

Comment: if one listing can only ever have one reason for being hiddden, then an extra field in the listings table would do. but since you're saying that one listing can have multiple reasons for being hidden you need to have a second  or maybe third table with the reasons.

Comment: With a bit field it's easy to have 64 reasons and you could always add a second field - although that makes it a tad cumbersome. Plus you don't need a separate table for the reasons, just a list of constants in code. The main advantage of couse is that it's super fast.

Comment: @davogotland - hance the bit field - each bit being one reason.

Comment: right mrki, a bit field would do the trick! the reasons are numbered 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and so on. and then you **or** them together to have multiple reasons on one row.

Comment: @mrki haha, i was writing my comment as you posted yours D:

Comment: Won't bit wise be slow as I would be able to use an index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow a user (for example, yourself :) ) to come up with their own reason, add a `varchar(255)` nullable field to your table to store the reason, and then query your table your table using `where hide_reason is null` or something.

If you want a fixed number of reasons that you can change occasionally by changing the table definition, use an `ENUM` field: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html. (I don't know which database you're using, so I'll use my favorite one)

If you want a fixed number of reasons that you can change with not too much effort, and that you can show in a dropdown list for your users to choose from, @davogotland's solution really is the best. Adding a table is not that excessive in a database environment ;)

In any case, you could always choose to use a separate `is_hidden` field alongside your `hide_reason` field, for clarity, or because you want to remember the reason someone hid a field also when they unhide it again, or whatever. If you do, use a `BIT` / `boolean` / `TINYINT` field for this.

EDIT:

Ah, wait. I misread the answer above. You want a fixed set of reasons, and you want each listing to be able to have more than one reason. This means you are in a many-to-many situation (each listing can have more than one reason, and each reason can be assigned to more than one listing). There are 3 ways to do this that I am aware of:

1. The way you outlined above. Use "bits", or powers of 2. Great.
2. Use a `SET` data type, which is like an `ENUM` but with the possibility of having more than one value in it. see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html. If you are using MS Access, there is a "Lookup Wizard" datatype which seems to do something similar (and supposedly includes an actual lookup wizard).
3. Use a link table, linking the listings to the reasons. You will need 2 new tables, `reasons` and `listings_reasons`, which look like this:

reasons:

```
reason_id
reason_text
```

listings_reasons:

```
listing_id
reason_id
```

Now, fill your `reasons` table with possible reasons, and link them to the listings using the `listings_reasons` table. This is the most common solution, since it allows you to add possible reasons without modifying your database structure.

Good luck!

Comment: I do already have an is_hidden field which is a date, but I need cater for multiple reasons.

Comment: Ah, right. I added some ways to do a many-to-many field. Incidentally, what kind of database are you using?

Comment: Hmmm, not seen `SET` would I be able to use this with an index, would it be slow ? It just a fancy function to use CSV ?

Comment: Actually, I believe it's pretty much a bitwise thing under the hood. Apparently you can even use functions like `BIT_OR` to make your life easier, there is an example on the `SET` page. However, you have to use MySQL.

Comment: Can you give me an example of BIT_OR and how I would work with actual values. Say I have options 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 and my field value was 12.

Comment: Ah, huh. Apparently that's an aggregate function, so you could use it to get all the items that are set in your query results. If you want to find option 4 in a field, you would use `WHERE field & 4` or using the FIND_IN_SET function: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value', field) > 0` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). All this information can be found on the "SET data type" page I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you said

> one listing has many reasons to be hidden

you implement the "one to many" relationship by giving the "many"-side a foreign key pointing to one of the rows in your "one" side. in this case this would mean two tables:

```
listing
reason_to_hide_listing
```

listing will probably have an id (int), and some text (text).

reason_to_hide_listing will have its own id (int), a foreign key column called listing_id (int), and a column named reason (text).

to find out if a listing is hidden, query the table reason_to_hide_listing for a listing_id equal to the listing you want to know if you should display or not. if one or more rows come back, this listing shouldn't be displayed.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reason_to_hide_listing WHERE listing_id = ?;
```

to find out all the reasons why one listing isn't displayed, select the reason from the table reason_to_hide_listing where the foreign key is the id of the listing at hand.

```
SELECT reason FROM reason_to_hide_listing WHERE listing_id = ?;
```

to hide a listing, and at the same time add a reason to why it's hidden, just insert a new row in reason_to_hide_listing with a listing_id pointing to the listing you want to hide.

```
INSERT INTO reason_to_hide_listing(listing_id, reason) VALUES(?, ?);
```

Comment: See my comment above, I don't have that many reasons. I think that creating a table of reasons seems a bit excessive. I was hoping for some kind of number code, but I'm not sure how this would work. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: did you see mrki's suggestion for a bitfield? that would work :)

Comment: I think this is probably the best idea (as I already said below). Adding lookup tables is not excessive at all, and also allows you to create dropdown lists and such. +1

Comment: +1 for a suggestion that will most likely result in the smallest "listing" table. I assume that most listings will NOT be hidden.

Comment: I've been told the the bitwise approach could be slow as I wouldn't be able to use an index.

Comment: This is the approach I would take. You could also condense the logic into one table where each row corresponds to a listing and there are multiple columns indicating the reasons. But this becomes less manageable as you add reasons and isn't as easy to index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Enumeration type as bit flags and store the value as an int in the database. Then all you need is a table to store the int and a FK of the related page.

```
[Flags]
enum HideReasons {
    None = 0x0,
    SomeReason = 0x1,
    OtherReason = 0x2
}
```

page.ReasonsToHide = HideReasons.SomeReason | HideReasons.OtherReason;

Edit: Just realized you may not be using C#. Hope this helps anyways.